# How can I get form responses in Google sheets to merge via array?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So, this works (kind of):

```
= IFERROR(JOIN( "," , FILTER('Form Responses 1'!Z3:AA3, NOT('Form Responses 1'!Z3:AA3 = "") )))
```

Columns from Z3 to AA3 are all merged and displayed properly in a single column. However, this will not work when a new form response comes in. So, I have to use an array. The array looks something like this:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN('Form Responses 1'!B4),'Form Responses 1'!B4))
```

Great. But, I can't define a range. Let's say, I want all values merged from Z3 to AA3 like I have above. I can't get it to work in an array. Anybody know how?

Edit:

This is close... but it sends junk to a right column:

```
=transpose(query(transpose('Form Responses 1'!Z2:AA2),,COLUMNS(Z2:AA2)))
```

I need everything to stay in a single column

Answer (score 0):

```
=transpose(query(transpose('Form Responses 1'!Z2:AA2),,COLUMNS('Form Responses 1'!Z2:AA2)))
```